# What determines whether a person can be in charge of a certain development position?

Tags: game-dev-story

Obviously Writers, Designers, and Sound Engineers can be the lead in their respective fields, but sometimes I can have a Sound Engineer take the lead on graphics.  Sometimes I can have Hacker A perform any job while Hacker B can only perform two.  What determines who you assign to each development position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What their *current* job is isn't the criteria. It's whether they have *any* job ranking in writer/designer/sound engineer that matters.

Comment: This makes me wish I didn't hire two of my hackers outright. I never should've fire Newb Ownerton!

Comment: Train them up, then use the career change manual to turn them into writers.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, as long as they are at least level 1 in the related job, they will be visible.

And you definitely should not keep Newb Ownerton! He has a terribly small energy bar :)